# SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA queries returning unexpectedly small resultsets

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server;
`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` Queries that were returning results today aren't returning any results today.

I even tried this:

```
select DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

And I've only gotten 6 results, although there are hundreds of tables in one database.

For a moment, I thought perhaps the scheduled backup might be running and interfering somehow, but it isn't supposed to start for another few minutes

Comment: Are you sure the same user is running the query as usual - somebody who has access to all hundreds of tables?

Comment: I also think it should be access related issue.

Comment: I will have to check tomorrow. I thought the same session was still open. Queries to the regular tables had the usual results, but the schema queries did not.